# Word VSTO before-BeforeSave event?

Tags: events, ms-word, vsto

Word has several events to hook into, to control application behavior etc.
Some of these events are: Document.BeforeSave and Application.BeforeSave
As far as I know, they do the same thing - they allow you to perform actions before the new document is saved, or even cancel the save event entirely.

But in later versions of Word, there seems to be an event happening BEFORE the BeforeSave events.

It shows a "Save this file" dialog:

[image: Save this file dialog]

Once the user has chosen where to save, and click [Save], THEN is the BeforeSave event executed.

I need a way to intercept this dialog, to prevent the user from saving in certain situations.
While I *can* do that with the current BeforeSave event, it results in a very bad user experience, since the user first chooses where to save, only to then be told that the time spent doing that was for nothing since the document is not allowed to be saved at this time.

In earlier versions of Word this was not an issue, Word just showed the regular (simple) Save As dialog whenever the user wanted to save the new document.

Coding in VB, I've tried these two ways to handle the BeforeSave Events at Document-level and Application-level. Both fire too late.
(C# code is also welcome, it's easily translated to VB in this context.)

```
' --- Handle BeforeSave at Document-level
Dim vstoDoc As Document = Globals.Factory.GetVstoObject(Me.Application.ActiveDocument)
    AddHandler vstoDoc.BeforeSave, AddressOf clsWord.ThisDocument_BeforeSave

Public Shared Sub ThisDocument_BeforeSave(sender As Object, e As SaveEventArgs)
    ' Do stuff...
End Sub

' --- Handle BeforeSave at Application-level
Private Sub HandleDocumentBeforeSaveEvent(document As Word.Document, ByRef SaveAsUI As Boolean, ByRef Cancel As Boolean) Handles _wordApplication.DocumentBeforeSave
    ' Do stuff...
End Sub
```

How do I intercept the new dialog?
Alternatively, is there another way to prevent the user from saving the document (like setting a document property or something)?

Answer (score 1):

I found a way.

First part is to expand the ribbon markup to include a `<commands>` node above the `<ribbon>` element (if any).

```
<commands>
  <command idMso="FileSave" getEnabled="FileSave_GetEnabled"/>
  <command idMso="FileSaveAs" getEnabled="FileSaveAs_GetEnabled"/>
</commands>
```

Then add callback methods to the ribbon code file:

```
Public Function FileSave_GetEnabled(ribControl As Office.IRibbonControl) As Boolean
  ' Simple test to toggle enabled/disabled easily
  ' - requires ribbon invalidation for changes to take effect though
  Return My.Computer.Keyboard.CapsLock
End Function

Public Function FileSaveAs_GetEnabled(ribControl As Office.IRibbonControl) As Boolean
  Return FileSave_GetEnabled(ribControl)
End Function
```

Finally you need to handle the BeforeSave event:

```
Private Sub HandleDocumentBeforeSaveEvent(Doc As Word.Document, ByRef SaveAsUI As Boolean, ByRef Cancel As Boolean) Handles _wdApp.DocumentBeforeSave
  If MessageBox.Show("Do you REALLY want to save the document?", "BeforeSave", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) = DialogResult.No Then
    Cancel = True
    Exit Sub
  End If
End Sub
```

This allows you to disable the "Save"-icon in the top of the ribbon, Ctrl+S and the "Save" option in the File menu.

It does not disable the "Save as" option in the file menu, but whenever a user tries to save from there, the BeforeSave event is executed, allowing you to take action there.

All in all, a better solution than previously achieved!